# Wordpress Plugin to display posts like Pinterest

Tags: wordpress

My client would like to be able to display his posts with a look similar to Pinterest.  I've searched the plugins for Wordpress, but I only see plugins that integrate Pinterest into a site - whereas i just want the look & feel of Pinterest.  Is anyone aware of a plugin that does this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Masonry Layout plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-masonry-layout/).  There's a free version that will probably get you what you need, but there are also more advanced features in their Pro version.  Check out their [default demo](http://www.masonrylayout.com/masonry-theme-demo/default/).

If you're looking to do more customization and want to learn how to do this, I'd recommend Josh Pollock's tutorial [How to Use Masonry to Add Pinterest Style Post Grid in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-use-masonry-to-add-pinterest-style-post-grid-in-wordpress/).